# SSRS Expression for current monday and current friday

Tags: reporting-services, expression, dateadd, dateinterval

I have the following expression for a text box on a report in SSRS

```
="TR1's Sent Between "+Format(dateadd(DateInterval.Day,1-WeekDay(Today), Today), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

this returns sundays date rather than mondays. does anyone know how to show the current monday's date and current fridays? if you could explain each section so i understand the format that would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using these two expression:

For `Mondays` you can use something like this:

`=Format(Today.AddDays(1-WeekDay(Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)),"dd/MM/yyyy")`

For `Fridays` you can use:

```
=FORMAT(Today.AddDays(5-WeekDay(Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday)),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

The first problem with your expression is that you are not specifying the first day of week in the `WeekDay` function, if your expression is returning the sunday date your system default first day of week is Sunday.

My expression takes today's date and add/substract the number of days required to get the first day of week: Monday. As I set the first day of week in my expression by using `FirstDayOfWeek.Monday` it calculates `1-1 = 0` it will add zero days to the today's date since today is monday (at least now in Colombia).

For Friday is similar, Friday is the 5 day of the week so you have to add/substract the required number of days to the today date to get its date. `5-1 = 4` (5 - **1** Today's day of week, taking in account monday is the first day), now just add 4 days to the today date and it will return the friday date.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for that it worked great and thanks for explaining how it works